# Nunit in VS Tutorial

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nunit

I'm looking for a tutorial that shows how to use NUnit's integration with visual studio to set up some simple unit tests, does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See here for a set of videos.](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/NUnit)